# вывод url из background-image без кавычек

Tags: php, парсер, phpquery

занимаюсь парсингом, написал на php, и встал такой вопрос, как сделать чтобы при парсинге, выводилась чистая ссылка?

вот код:

```
"img" => 'https://site.ru'.$pq->find('.constructor__image.is-visible')->attr('style')
```

выводится так:

```
https://site.rubackground-image: url('/upload/merged_picture/620563ca25fc94ef404ba5ed72920de3/image.png');
```

хотелось бы так:

```
https://site.ru/upload/merged_picture/620563ca25fc94ef404ba5ed72920de3/image.png
```

подскажите как так сделать?

Comment: то есть, задача стоит в том, чтобы убрать "background-image: url('')"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте с помощью регулярного выражения `"#url\('(?<url>.*)'\)#`:

```php
$url = "https://site.ru";
$string = "background-image: url('/upload/merged_picture/620563ca25fc94ef404ba5ed72920de3/image.png');";

preg_match("#url\('(?<url>.*)'\)#", $string, $matches);

if (!empty($matches) && !empty($matches['url'])) {
    echo "https://site.ru{$matches['url']}";
}
```

- `url\('` - начало поиска
- `('(?<url>.*)` - группа с именем **url**
- `'\)` - конеч поиска

Соответственно, возьмется значение между `url\('` и `'\)`.

Comment: `.*?` не надо жадный поиск там делать

Comment: и вместо этих `empty` надо просто проверит результат `preg_match`

Comment: @teran про жадный поиск не понял, можешь пояснить? Про empty согласен, немного лишние проверки, но вдруг там пишут `url('')`? А так, эти проверки просто позволят ничего не делать.